# Bind handler to form 'ajax:success' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a form and I'm using [magicsuggest](https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest) library to convert a text field into tag field.
**My form**:

```
= form_for @question, remote: true do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.label :tag_list
    = f.text_field :tag_list, class: 'suggest-tag'
  = f.submit
```

**My script**:

```
$('.suggest-tag').magicSuggest({
  data: ['Paris', 'London']
});
```

After AJAX form submit, I re-render that form from response but input field isn't converted to tag field as magicsuggest is no longer 'associated' with new field.
How can I bind a handler to 'ajax:success' event or something, so that magicsuggest is instantiated properly on a new field after form is re-rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call your js script at the bottom of your ajax file(js.erb). This way your script will be called after your ajax action.

Update:

Suppose your text-field has an id 'tag' then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#tag",function(){
  $('.suggest-tag').magicSuggest({
    data: ['Paris', 'London']
  });
});
```

Comment: I thought about it but it would be code duplication, that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @leemour if you want to bind it to "ajax:success" event then i'm afraid that's the right place. You can try jquery "live/on" event handler. It won't bind it to ajax:success but i think it should work. Check my updated answer.